# PHP - NULL added at the end of a string inserting hour in mysql varchar

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have a really strange (for me) problem.
I have a Mysql db where i store opening hours of a store:
This is the table stucture

```
#   Nome        Tipo            Codifica caratteri  </br>
1   id          int(11)         No</br>
2   store_slug  varchar(50)     utf8_unicode_ci </br>
3   dow         tinyint(4)      No</br>
4   type        varchar(2)      utf8_unicode_ci </br>
5   open        varchar(10)     utf8_unicode_ci</br>    
6   close       varchar(10)     utf8_unicode_ci </br>
7   extra_text  varchar(50)     utf8_unicode_ci</br>
```

I get time as input in a one php file and another php file insert that input data to the database.The problem is here:

```
<?php $open_d = $hours[$i]["d"]["o"];
      $close_d =  $hours[$i]["d"]["c"];
      $type = "d";
      $sql = "INSERT INTO `".MLS_PREFIX."store_hours`(store_slug,dow,type,open,close) VALUE('$store_slug',$i,'$type','$open_d','$close_d')";
      echo $sql ;
      echo "</br>";
      if($db->query($sql)){ echo "Store saved !"; } else { echo "Some error came up ! "; }

?>
```

For example Resulting SQL insert for 1 row is :

```
INSERT INTO `aCr_store_hours`(store_slug,dow,type,open,close) VALUE('haki',1,'d','13:01','15:00')
```

When I copy and execute this SQL in phpmyadmin all works fine but if i use the PHP script with the same SQL the time in 'open' and 'close' columns will be something like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLdrr.jpg)

Can, please, someone help me with this really strange problem?

Thanks and have a nice day!

Regards

Michele

Comment: Could you show the `$hours` value please? Perhaps a NULL character is inserted at the end of the variable.

Comment: Colons are often used to prefix placeholders in prepared statements, which would explain how the `:00` portions of the string are being replaced with null. You don't say which DB library you're using, but you might need to escape the string differently.

Comment: Try using prepared statements and parameter binding. Here is the information for [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: @iainn Does that happen even when `prepare()` isn't used? Seems like a weird thing to happen.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton If that's the MySQLI `query` method then no, but it could be a custom function that's expecting some params to also be provided. I can't say I've seen a library that would work like this, but it would explain the results.

Comment: @iainn Fair enough.

Comment: Is your database connection in unicode? It may be an encoding problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the colon in your query.  Try prefixing all colons with backslashes.

Comment: The colon ':' isn't a special character, it's in the `'`. So why this character should be escaped?

Comment: Manually escaping specific characters is a *really* bad way to go about escaping SQL statements

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks all. I solved.

For reference i use this class
 * @author col.shrapnel@gmail.com
 * @link http://phpfaq.ru/safemysql

and, like someone told here i only need to bind my params using class

Now my PHP looks like this

```
($db->query("INSERT INTO `".MLS_PREFIX."store_hours`(store_slug,dow,type,open,close) VALUE (?s, ?i, ?s, ?s, ?s )",$store_slug,$i,$type,$open_d,$close_d))
```

and all works fine.

Thanks and have a nice day!!

Michele